# Is there a way to collect data in multiple excel files?

Tags: java

there are 12 excel files that contain different products sales data, I try to sum up each month and entire year's sales using java but I can't add up sales for the whole year. Is there a way to do that? Thanks for your help.

```
public class Main {

public  static void listOfSales(String fileName,String month){

    List<PriceList> list = readsListFroExcel(fileName);

    int sumOfInYearSale = 0;
    int sumOfInOnlineSale =0;
    int sumOfTotalMonthlySale = 0;
    for (PriceList x : list){

        sumOfInYearSale = sumOfInYearSale + x.getTotalPhysicalSale();
        sumOfInOnlineSale = sumOfInYearSale + x.getTotalOnlineSale();
    }
    System.out.println(month +" Physical Sales : "+sumOfInYearSale);
    System.out.println(month+ " Online Sales :" +sumOfInOnlineSale);

}
private static List<PriceList> readsListFroExcel(String fileName) {

    List<PriceList> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Path pathTofile = Paths.get(fileName);

    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(pathTofile)){

        String headerLine = br.readLine();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line!=null){
          String[] attributes = line.split(",");
          PriceList listOfPrice =  createList(attributes);

          list.add(listOfPrice);

          line = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return list;

}
```

}

Comment: Try using joinery. It's similar to pandas and numpy: https://github.com/cardillo/joinery.

Comment: and Apache's POI also might help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am trying to do without using Apache's POI